# Discovering Lantronix XPort Pro and XPort using C# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to find Lantronix XPort Pro devices on a network using C#. I am using some python code that I found on the Lantronix developer wiki as an example http://wiki.lantronix.com/developer/Lantronix_Discovery_Protocol.

The application I am writing is written in C# and I need to discover our units that have Lantronix devices installed. It seems that when I do the socket.RecieveFrom function call it just seems to hang the app.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong. The python code from the link above detects the devices correctly. I should be able to duplicate this in C#.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
   private void FindLantronixXPort()
    {
        // This is the socket code that will broadcast from 
        // the local machine looking for responces from Lantronix
        // XPort servers

        // Create the array for our message chars
        char[] chars = new char[4];

        // Build the actual message
        chars[0] = Convert.ToChar(0);
        chars[1] = Convert.ToChar(0);
        chars[2] = Convert.ToChar(0);
        chars[3] = Convert.ToChar(0xf6);

        // Convert the chars to a message string
        string msg = new string(chars);

        // Convert the setring to a byte array
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

        // Get the local machines IP address
        string Local_IP = GetIPAddress();

        // Now create a broadcast UDP socket
        Socket XmtSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        XmtSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);

        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Local_IP), LantronixPort);

        // Broadcast the packet
        XmtSock.SendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, iep);

        XmtSock.Close();

        // Wait 500 mili seconds
        int milliseconds = 500;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

        Socket RcvSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, LantronixPort);

        RcvSock.Bind(iep);

        EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;

        Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");

        byte[] data1 = new byte[120];

        int recv = RcvSock.ReceiveFrom(data1, data1.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ep);

        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data1, 0, recv);

        Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}",
                              stringData, ep.ToString());

        RcvSock.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I looked at the source code of your Link.  It looks like the code is connecting to : "http://wiki.lantronix.com".  So why are you trying to connect to a UDP port in your c# code?

Comment: The  "wiki.lantronix.com" has example python code that I am trying to implement in c#. I am not connecting to that site. The code gets the IP address of my local machine and uses it to send discovery commands to find the Lantronix devices. I included the lantronix link in case anyone wanted to look at the python code I am using as an example.

Comment: See following posting that may help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4185e8f7-90dc-471e-a485-03567c64c816/how-to-capture-dhcpv6-ipv6-packets-in-c?forum=ncl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lantronix's wiki seems to be down at the moment, so I can't take a look at that for the moment. However, looking at your code it seems that you have to broadcast a UDP message, wait some time, and then check to see if anything has responded to that message.

However, it looks like you're creating a brand new socket for receiving the responses, but only after half a second. It's highly likely that any X-port that is going to respond will already have done so long before then (networks are fast, X-ports aren't very sluggish, etc). So I reckon the responses are hitting your OS'es network stack, which saying "well I dunno where that's supposed to go", and only after half a second are you creating a socket suitable for receiving the responses that the OS'es network stack has already discarded as unknown junk.

So move things around a bit is what I suggest. Set up the receiving socket, binding and endpoint *before* you transmit the broadcast message, so that it's ready there waiting for responses. See if that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I thought too. The receiving socket should ideally be open and listening before the UDP Broadcast is sent. I'd also suggest looking into asynchronous methods. Microsoft has a nice example with for Sockets, although they use BeginAccept instead of BeginReceiveFrom (=async ReceiveFrom) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: The Lantronix wiki is back up http://wiki.lantronix.com/developer/Lantronix_Discovery_Protocol. This python code does what I want. I need to get the IP address of the XPort devices responding to the broadcast. Is there a way to do this in C#? I only need to check one byte in the returned packet. If that  is correct I need to determine the IP address of the responding device. This is what the example python code does.

Comment: OK, I got it to get correct responses from the XPort devices using this code. I switched to using async calls. I now need to get the IP address of the devices that respond. Is there a way to do this in C#? I can post my latest code is needed.

Comment: @WJD, I don't know first hand, but perhaps this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964846/get-client-ip-from-udp-packages-received-with-udpclient

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. I got it to find the XPort devices using async UDP socket. I determined the IP address of each of the responding units by using ((IPEndPoint)epServer1).Address.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

@WJD Your code for preparing byte array did not create content expected by XPort. It is why it did not replyed and hang on RecieveFrom(). 
I followed the link you gave for python example and created version in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket socket;
        int GroupPort = 30718;
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
            var localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.14"), GroupPort);    // <-- your local IP address

            socket.Bind(localEP);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to create socket. " + e.Message);
            return;
        }


        var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, GroupPort);
        try
        {
            byte[] messageBytes;
            messageBytes = new byte[0];
            messageBytes = AddByteToArray(messageBytes, 0xf6);
            messageBytes = AddByteToArray(messageBytes, 0);
            messageBytes = AddByteToArray(messageBytes, 0);
            messageBytes = AddByteToArray(messageBytes, 0);

            socket.SendTo(messageBytes, remoteEP);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to send message. " + e.Message);
            return;
        }


        var recvEp = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var recvBytes = new byte[1024];
                var receivedCount = socket.ReceiveFrom(recvBytes, ref recvEp);
                var receivedArray = recvBytes.Take(receivedCount).ToArray();
                var receivedArrayAsHexString = string.Join("", receivedArray.Select(c => String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))));
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedArray);
                Console.WriteLine($"Broadcast Respond from client {recvEp.ToString()} returned: {receivedArrayAsHexString}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                socket.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static byte[] AddByteToArray(byte[] bArray, byte newByte)
    {
        byte[] newArray = new byte[bArray.Length + 1];
        bArray.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
        newArray[0] = newByte;
        return newArray;
    }

}
```